# How to calculate a reverse scale factor?

Tags: geometry

I trying to scale object up and back down, I can only use a scale factor to alter the size.
I am currently scaling upwards by 1.2.

*How do I calculate the scale factor I need to return the object to its' original 100%?*

Comment: Ratio and proportion. If object a is twice as large as object b, then object b is half the size of object a. If object a is $1.2$ times the size of object b, then ______. (fill in the blank)

Comment: object a is 5/6 the size of object a?

Comment: "Object b is...", you mean. That's basically it; reciprocate the scale factor you once used to undo the scaling.

Comment: sorry yes object b, ok thanks, i think i get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To settle this question: we always have the relation that if some object B is $p$ times larger than object A, then we can also say that object A is $\frac1{p}$ times the size of object B. In the OP's case, to undo the $\frac65 \times$ scale-up, a multiplication by $1/(6/5)=\frac56$ is needed.

Comment: I have a question:
The way you are doing this problem...
Do you use Dimensional Analysis????

Comment: You could call it that, yes.